# Re-opened nested module anomaly in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module, nested

Why does re-opening a nested module give different results depending on the syntax used? For example, this works fine:

```
module A
  module E
  end
end
module A
  module E
    def E.e
    end
  end
end
```

But this:

```
module A
  module E
  end
end
module A::E
  def E.e
  end
end
```

gives the error:

```
reopen.rb:6:in `<module:E>': uninitialized constant A::E::E (NameError)
from reopen.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

(Before someone points this out, a workaround is to use `self` instead of the module name when defining E.e, but that's not really the point of this post.)

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Fair point - rephrased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `module` keyword sets a namespace context that is checked for references to existing names of Modules. These namespaces are then searched inner-to-outer to resolve references to Module (and Class) names.

In your first example, it *looks* like you may need to define `E.e` inside `module E` block, but in fact you don't:

```
module A
  module E
  end
end
module A
  def E.e
  end
end
```

What happens in both your examples is that Ruby looks at the current namespace, and tries `<namespace>::E` as a module name. So in both examples, the first thing it checks is in fact `A::E::E` which does not exist. Then it falls back to the next context. Which is where the examples differ: In the first example it is `A::E` which is valid, in the second example, it is just `E` which is not. The error that it then throws relates to the first name it checked.

Comment: Interesting. IMO `module A::E` creating a non-nested context with a "nested" name is a bug. If it was equivalent to:

    `module A
      module E
        ...`

I'd say that would be much closer to normal intuition about namespaces.

Comment: Yes, it always creates a single context, within the `module` block. It is at least self-consistent in that respect. I cannot see any reason why it couldn't be made to work another way, except for historical reasons - there may even be code out there that relies on the current behaviour - where `E` and `A::E` are both defined for instance.

Comment: Fair enough. Perhaps raising the issue here might cause it to percolate into a future version of Ruby.