# Nesting versus namespace operator

Tags: ruby, module, namespaces

I had believed that

```
module A
  module B
    ...
  end
end
```

and (provided that module `A` is defined in advance):

```
module A::B
  ...
end
```

are equivalent, but it turned out not. Given:

```
module A
  C = :foo
end
```

the two forms behave differently:

```
module A
  module B
    puts C
  end
end
# => :foo

module A::B
  puts C
end
# => NameError: uninitialized constant A::B::C
```

What is the logic behind this difference? Particularly, why cannot `A::B` access `A::C` in the second form (although it can in the first form)?

---

**Update**

I found some related posts on the Ruby core:

- https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5148
- https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6810

Comment: I think I answered something very similar before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589997/re-opened-nested-module-anomaly-in-ruby/17591421#17591421

Comment: In short, use of `class` or `module` defines a *single* namespace context in which symbol names are searched. Ruby does not traverse the nested namespaces like it was ascending folders, instead it checks them in sequence from the declarations, like it was working through a `PATH`

Comment: @NeilSlater I see. The linked question indeed is related. It is actually a special case or a result that is due to the problem that I ask here. And your answer there can be an answer to my question as well, but it seems to me that it only states they are different, without providing the reason why.

Comment: I do not know the design reason why. As a conjecture, it is more flexible in that it allows the developer to control which namespaces are considered when finding a symbol. However, it is also a way to trip developers up, because it is rarely important.

Answer (score 1):

[Module::nesting](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-c-nesting) is a good tool to answer you here. As the doc is saying - ***Returns the list of Modules nested at the point of call.***

Here is the reason why the below one is not working :

```
module A
  C = :foo
end

module A::B
  puts C
end
```

To let this explain I would write something like below :

```
module A
  C = :foo
end

module A::B
  $a = Module.nesting
end
$a # => [A::B]
```

So from the output of `$a`,it is clear that why the constant `C` is not accessible.

The reason why the below code does work :

```
module A
  C = :foo
end
module A
  module B
    puts C
  end
end
```

To let this explain I would write something like below :

```
module A
  C = :foo
end

module A
  module B
    $a = Module.nesting
  end
end
$a # => [A::B, A]
```

So from the output of `$a`,it is clear that why the constant `C` is accessible.

Read here([**Everything you ever wanted to know about constant lookup in Ruby**](http://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup)) is an wonderful resource for the same I just found.